# ubuntu11.10でカレントディレクトリのファイル名に含まれた複数のスペースを_(アンダースコア)に変換する方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ubuntu11.10でカレントディレクトリのファイル名に含まれた複数のスペースを_(アンダースコア)に変換する方法についてご教授頂きたいです。変換したいファイルはカレントディレクトリに×× ×× ××（××は英数字）のような名前で複数あります。
hoge.shというシェルスクリプト中でrenameコマンドを実行しているのですが、

```
$ cat hoge.sh
#!/bin/sh

rename 's/ /_/;' ./*
```

下記のようなエラーが出てしまう状態です。

```
$ ./hoge.sh
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/bin/rename line 59.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名に改行が含まれていて、`rename` コマンドがそれを扱えないのかも知れません。
以下のように、改行も `_` に変換するとどうでしょうか。

```bash
rename 's/[ \n\r]/_/g' ./*
```

改行はそのままにしたい場合は、例えば bash なら以下のような方法があります。

```bash
for file in ./*; do mv -i "$file" "${file// /_}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

パターンの指定部分に恐らく;(セミコロン)は不要なのと、スペースが複数含まれるケースを考慮すると
`$ rename "s/ /_/g" ./*`